# Error in adding two polynomials expressions

Tags: c, function, math, struct, polynomials

I was trying to to do operations on two polynomial expressions,while i was adding two numbers,in some cases it gives the correct answer,while in other cases like x^2 + x adding with x + 1, it gives wrong answer.

In the program first I stored the expressions into an array,then sorted the array on the basis of exponent(in descending order),then i compare two expressions,and adds according to the program.
Expression[0].coeff stores the number of elements in expression.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
typedef struct {
    float coeff;
    int expo;
}poly;

void sort(poly E[])
{
    int n = E[0].coeff,tempExpo,tempCoeff;
    for(int i=1;i<=n-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=n-1-i;j++)
        {
            if(E[j].expo < E[j+1].expo)
            {
                  tempExpo =  E[j].expo;
                  tempCoeff = E[j].coeff;
                  E[j].expo = E[j+1].expo;
                  E[j].coeff = E[j+1].coeff;
                  E[j+1].expo = tempExpo;
                  E[j+1].coeff = tempCoeff;

            }
        }
    }
}
void input(poly Exp[])
{

    int counter = 1; 
    float coeff;
    int expo;
    printf("\nEnter the coeffecient and exponent in sorted order (press 0 0 to end process) :\n");
    while(1)       
    {
        scanf("%f%d",&coeff,&expo);
        if(coeff == 0 && expo == 0)
        {
            Exp[0].coeff = counter--;//size of array is the first coeffecient
            sort(Exp);
            break;
        } 
        Exp[counter].coeff = coeff;
        Exp[counter].expo = expo;
        counter++;
    }
}   

void print(poly Exp[])
{
    int n = Exp[0].coeff,counter = 1;
    printf("\nExpression :");
    while(n>1)
    {
        printf("%.1f x^%d ",Exp[counter].coeff,Exp[counter].expo);
        n--;
        if(n!= 1)
            printf(" + ");
        counter ++;
        
   
    }

} 



void add(poly E1[],poly E2[],poly R[])
{
    int n = E1[0].coeff;
    int m =  E2[0].coeff;

    int i=1,k=1,j=1;

    while(i<=n && j<=m)
    {
        if(E1[i].expo > E2[j].expo)
        {
            R[k].coeff =  E1[i].coeff;
            R[k].expo =  E1[i].expo;
            k++;i++;
        }

        else if(E1[i].expo == E2[j].expo)
        {
            R[k].coeff =  E1[i].coeff + E2[j].coeff ;
            R[k].expo =  E1[i].expo;
            k++;i++;j++;
        }
 
        else
        {
            R[k].coeff =  E2[j].coeff;
            R[k].expo =  E2[j].expo;
            k++;j++;
        }
    }

    while(i<=n)
    {
        R[k].coeff =  E1[i].coeff;
        R[k].expo =  E1[i].expo;
        k++;i++;
    }

    while(j<=m)
    {
        R[k].coeff =  E2[j].coeff;
        R[k].expo =  E2[j].expo;
        k++;j++;
    }
    
    R[0].coeff= k-1 ;

}


int main()
{
    
    poly E1[100],E2[100],R[100];
    char op;
    R[0].coeff = 0;
       
    input(E1);
    print(E1);
    
    input(E2);
    print(E2);
    add(E1,E2,R);
    printf("\nAfter addition ");
    print(R);


return 0;
}
```

I know its a bit long code,can someone help to find where its getting wrong and changes to correct it.

Comment: You've been told before about [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Test your input functions, and if they work correctly, remove them and hard-code the two input polynomials.

Comment: ...And when I try your example, I get x^2 + 2x + 1, which is correct. What do you get?

Comment: :1.0 x^2  + 2.0 x^1  + 18070118169971718619136.0 x^6 .This is what i am getting @Beta

Comment: And when you hard-code the input polynomials?

Comment: Thanks for the hard coding tip @Beta,problem was actually with input  and print function.